# How to apply quantile to pandas groupby object?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas groupby object called `grouped`. I can get `grouped.mean()` and other simple functions to work, but I cannot get `grouped.quantile()` to work. I get the following error when attempting to run `grouped.quantile()`:

```
ValueError: ('invalid literal for float(): groupA', u'occurred at index groups')
```

I am grouping by text labels, so I am not sure why the function tries to convert it to a float. It should be computing the quantile using the floats within each group. Can someone help to point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2625) has now been fixed, so you'll see it in the next version of pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like quantile() doesn't ignore the nuisance columns and is trying to find quantiles for your text columns.  Here's a trivial example:

```
In [75]: df = DataFrame({'col1':['A','A','B','B'], 'col2':[1,2,3,4]})

In [76]: df
Out[76]:
  col1  col2
0    A     1
1    A     2
2    B     3
3    B     4

In [77]: df.groupby('col1').quantile()
ValueError: ('could not convert string to float: A', u'occurred at index col1')
```

However, when I subset out only the numeric columns, I get:

```
In [78]: df.groupby('col1')['col2'].quantile()
Out[78]:
col1
A       1.5
B       3.5
```

Comment: I posted this as an [issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2625).

Comment: Thanks. Ideally quantile() should be automatically applied to all columns like mean(), but this solution works for me for now.